# How to loop using .split() function on a text file python

Tags: python, web-scraping

I have a html file with different team names written throughout the file.  I just want to grab the team names. The team names always occur after certain text and end before certain text, so I've split function to find the team name.  I'm a beginner, and I'm sure I'm making this harder than it is. Data is the file

```
teams = data.split('team-away">')[1].split("</sp")[0]
    for team in teams:
        print team
```

This returns each individual character for the first team that it finds (so for example, if teams = San Francisco 49ers, it prints "S", then "A", etc. instead of what I need it to do: Print "San Francisco 49ers" then on the next line the next team "Carolina Panthers", etc.

Thank you!

Comment: Parse the HTML. Don't work with it as a string.

Comment: [Déjà vu](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: Yeah, I wondered how long before someone links to "Tony the Pony". The  OP does state "I have a html file...The team names always occur after certain text and end before certain text" Assuming @sdeep27 is correctly describing the problem (and who would know but himself), then plain text search works 100% (but of course, not best practice).

Answer (score 2):

"I'm a beginner, and I'm sure I'm making this harder than it is."

Well, kind of.

```
import re
teams = re.findall('team-away">(.*)</sp', data)
```

(with credit to Kurtis, for a simpler regular expression than I originally had)

Though an actual [HTML parser](http://docs.python.org/2/library/htmlparser.html) would be best practice.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why is this regex superior to re.findall('team-away">(.*?)</sp', data)

Comment: @Kurtis, you are right. I had assumed that `findall` would match the *entire* regex, so I used lookbehind and lookahead. But if exactly one capture group exists, the returned match is only that group. Improving answer now.

Comment: so I went and looked over some re to understand your answer, and this does tackle it, thank you.  Quick question though, as I only need the letters returned and not numbers, I tried (\w*) instead of (.*) and it returned an empty list.  Do you know why this could be, or is \w the wrong expression to use?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean. Perhaps `([A-Za-z]*).*`?

Comment: isn't \w the regex identifier for all letters? How come we use the format [A-Za-z] instead?

Comment: @sdeep27, `\w` is all "word" characters, which consists of all ASCII letters and underscore.

Answer (score 0):

Don't re-invent the wheel! Look into [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/), it'll to the job for you.